# How to check for retina display in jQuery and serve double-resolution images accordingly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a little JS-script that checks window-width on resize event and serves different full-screen background images specified on the html-side in data-attributes accordingly. Unfortunately, I cannot use a CSS-solution in this particular case.

The solution on its own works, but it does not incorporate images for retina displays. If I see this correctly, images for retina displays need twice the resolution to be displayed correctly. I have set the following breakpoints in the script: 1280 x 720px (retina: 2560 x 1440) , 1920 x 1080 px (retina: 3840 x 2160), larger than 2560 x 1440 px (retina: 5120 x 2880).

**HTML:**

```
<section id="page-title" class="page-title-lg img-cover header-lg" data-bg-xxl="test/2560.jpg" data-bg-xl="test/fullhd.jpg" data-bg-lg="test/hdready.jpg">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="page-title-wrapper">
        <div class="page-title-txt">
          <h1>Large Page Title</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

**JS:**

```
function checkWidth(){

    var screenWidth = $window.width();

    if( screenWidth <= 1280 ){
        // Hd-ready desktop - 1280 x 720
        $('[data-bg-lg]').each(function() {
            var dataImg = $(this).attr('data-bg-lg');
            $(this).css('background-image', 'url(assets/img/' + dataImg + ')');
        });
    } else if ( screenWidth >= 1281 && screenWidth <= 1920 ) {
        // Full-hd desktop - 1920 x 1080
        $('[data-bg-xl]').each(function() {
            var dataImg = $(this).attr('data-bg-xl');
            $(this).css('background-image', 'url(assets/img/' + dataImg + ')');
        });
    } else {
        // Huge desktop - 2560 x 1440
        $('[data-bg-xxl]').each(function() {
            var dataImg = $(this).attr('data-bg-xxl');
            $(this).css('background-image', 'url(assets/img/' + dataImg + ')');
        });
    }

}
```

The question now is how to check for a retina / non-retina display and serve the correct image set with the double resolution accordingly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if [`window.devicePixelRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio) is higher than 1, and replace images with their high-resolution versions if it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = "(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi)";

if (matchMedia(query).matches) {
  // do high-dpi stuff
} else {
  // do non high-dpi stuff
}
```